# Surface mount capacitor value confirmation

Tags: capacitor, esr

I was just checking for some bad caps on my TV as I get a large distortion for a few minutes at power up.
The power board looked fine but I noticed some aluminium surface mount caps were bulging slightly on the control board (image attached ) so thought I would try to replace them.

Just wanted to confirm that these are 220 uF and I could just replace with through hole.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: How do I except a comment as an answer. I see no button ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those look like Panasonic VK / TK series 220 uF 35V parts.

You may be able to replace them with through hole parts, but these are surface mount.

The product page is [here](https://eu.industrial.panasonic.com/products/capacitors/aluminium-electrolytic-capacitors/aluminum-electrolytic-capacitors-surface-mount/series/tk-v/ABA0110?reset=1)

(Converted to answer).